# Memory leak when allocating memory inside function

Tags: c, memory, memory-leaks

I have a function that creates a string. This is the simple example:

```
char* getString() {
    char *buffer = (char*)malloc(20 * sizeof(char));

    snprintf(buffer, 20, "Some stupid text");

    return buffer;
}
```

And here is the main function:

```
int main() {
    printf("%s\n", getString());

    return 0;
}
```

Is memory leak happening in this code (because Valgrind does not warn about any memory leak)? If it is, how can I avoid this without using new variables in the main function?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you have a memory leak. And no there's no way to avoid it if you don't want to assign the pointers to a variable that you pass to `free`.

Comment: Yup, you should put it into a variable before `printf` and then `free` it

Comment: Just use valgrind it will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have definitely a leak here.

This is correct:

```
char* getString() {
    char *buffer = malloc(20 * sizeof(char));    
    snprintf(buffer, 20, "Some stupid text");    
    return buffer;
}    

int main() {
    char *mystring = getString();
    printf("%s\n", mystring);
    free(mystring);
    return 0;
}
```

But with your program valgrind should display that there is a leak.

Comment: `free(mystring)`

Comment: Yeah, I should know better than question that. I do like that myself.

Answer (score 3):

Yes and No you have a memory leak. Yes, you are not explicitly deleting the buffer allocated in your getString function. No, because this leak is occurring within main() with no looping, your buffer is getting deallocated when main () exits.

So, while what you are doing is bad coding practice, it is causing no harm in this particular situation.

You need to have some variables in main to get around this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have a leak. When you only call getstring without putting it in a variable, you lost the pointers to buffer.

A leak happen when you lose the pointer to the variable (i.e when you lose the "path" to your variable)